# Java HashMap put method isn't working

Tags: java, hashmap

I was trying to do an exercise creating a `PhoneBook` using `HashMap`.
However I see my `addPhone` method doesn't add a new phone to my `PhoneBook` `pb` i.e. `data.put(name, num);` method inside my `addPhone` doesn't put the data into the `HashMap` `data`.

Can somebody explain me what is wrong here?

**UPD**
Now I understand it was a mistake, I used `containsValue` method instead of `containsKey`. So simple!
But this question is not similar at all to the suggested already existing question. I was not asking `Is checking for key existence in HashMap always necessary?` I know about the ways to search the `HashMap` according to the key or to the value. This question is actually caused by a mistake. However I received a very wide and useful answers here. I believe these answers, especially davidxxx's answer is excellent and may be useful for many people.

```
import java.util.HashMap;


public class PhoneBook {

        private HashMap<String, String> data;

        public PhoneBook() 
        { 
            data = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
        } 
        public void addPhone(String name, String num) 
        { 
            data.put(name, num); 
        }


        //a
        public String getPhone(String name){
            if(data.containsValue(name)){
                return data.get(name);
            }
            else 
                return null;
        }

        //b
        public void ToString(){
            data.toString();
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            PhoneBook pb = new PhoneBook();
            pb.addPhone("shlomi", "12312413yuioyuio24");
            pb.addPhone("shlomi1", "1231345345241324");
            pb.addPhone("shlomi2", "12312445735671324");
            System.out.println(pb.getPhone("shlomi"));
            System.out.println(pb.getPhone("blat"));
            pb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You provide the name that is the key to `data.containsValue(name)` instead of the value.
What you need is `Map.containskey()` if you want to return the value according to the key from the client side of your class.

Note that handling the existence in the map is not required as `null` is returned as no mapping exists for a key :

```
public String getPhone(String name){       
     return data.get(name);      
}
```

---

**Side note**

Not the issue in the question but whatever an issue to handle.
`ToString()` is really not a good name for a method :

```
public void ToString(){
    data.toString();
}
```

Method names are case sensitive, yes, but it is not a fair reason to play with that to define a slightly different naming (here is the `T` uppercase) to the `Object.toString()` method. It makes the code reading misleading.
Besides, your method returns nothing. So this is helpless : `pb.ToString();`

What you should declare is :

```
@Override
public String toString(){
    return data.toString();
}
```

Adding `@Override` adds a compilation constraint that checks that the method is defined in the hierarchy.

Now you can for example write in the standard output the `toString()` representation of your `PhoneBook` object in this way :

```
System.out.println(pb);
```

Comment: @Eliyahu You are welcome :) I added an additional example to use the `toString()` from the client side as invoking only  `pb.ToString()` is still useless if you don't exploit the returned String.

Answer (score 2):

HashMap maps keys to values so it contains key-value pairs.

`containsValue()` it returns true if map maps one or more keys to the specified **value**

`containsKey()` It returns true if map contains a mapping for the specified **key**

Your case has `name` as key and `num` as value. In the method `getPhone()` you have parameter which corresponds to `name` and hence you should use `containsKey()` instead of `containsValue()`

Answer (score 1):

`data.containsValue(name)` checks whether the `HashMap` contains the **value** `name`. Since your `HashMap` contains name **keys** and number **values**, you should be calling `data.containsKey(name)`.

```
public String getPhone(String name){
    if(data.containsKey(name)) {
        return data.get(name);
    } else 
        return null;
}
```

or simply

```
public String getPhone(String name) {
    return data.get(name);
}
```